# Getting custom wp-posts sorted by multiple metadata-entries per post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

We got a wordpress site where we want to show a list of events which are comming, or already started but aren't done yet.

Therefor we made a custom post type called "events". Each event has its own wp_posts.ID and is linked to 2 (or more) wp_postmeta rows. The key value of one of the rows contain "event_start" (key) and a unix timestamp" as value. One of the others contains almost the same, but then "event_end" with a timestamp as value.

Now we want to do a query getting all the active and comming events sorted by startdate.

We tried some different ways, and i think this came close, but just didn't work, because the wp_post.ID isn't availble when we do the sub-select query..

```
    $sql = "
        SELECT
            $wpdb->posts.*, (
                    SELECT 
                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value
                    FROM 
                        $wpdb->postmeta
                    WHERE
                        $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
                    AND 
                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'event_start'
                    ) AS event_start,
                    (
                    SELECT 
                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value
                    FROM 
                        $wpdb->postmeta
                    WHERE
                        $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
                    AND 
                        $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'event_end'
                    ) AS event_end
        FROM
            $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
        WHERE (
            event_start > ".time()."

        )
        OR (
            event_start < ".time()."
            AND
            event_end > ".time()."
        )
        ORDER BY 
            event_start ASC
        LIMIT 0,3";
```

Who can help us figuring out how to get this data? Should we delete all the code and start over?

Thnx!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WP_Query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and [get_post_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta)

This helps you.